# Plotting the coverage of the confidence interval as a function of sample size using Monte Carlo in R

Tags: r, confidence-interval, monte-carlo

I have a distribution $x\sim\text{exponential}(\lambda)$ and I know that $\hat{\lambda}=\bar{x}$ and Fisher's information to be $\lambda^{-2}$. Now, I need to use `R` to generate the data from this distribution with $\hat{\lambda}=1$, and plot the coverage of the CI of the sample as a function of sample size for different sample sizes using 1000 Monte Carlo reps. 
All I have so far for `R` is:

```
 x=rexp(25,1)
> x
 [1] 0.14576099 0.78689809 0.56063641 1.70545364 0.40507393 0.22229612
 [7] 2.15959513 0.19580686 2.14139285 0.30020825 1.04155197 0.11201061
[13] 0.11249431 4.12707736 0.35781892 0.81850649 0.06649549 2.35163544
[19] 0.23481295 0.54353838 0.34712200 0.71332001 0.55924596 0.50507862
[25] 0.41171776
> tcrit<-qt(0.975,24)
> tcrit
[1] 2.063899
> mu<-mean(x)
> mu
[1] 0.8370219
> sig<-sqrt(var(x))
> sig
[1] 0.9603002
> hist(x)
```

I don't know how to create these CI's in `R`.

Comment: Is this for a course or a homework assignment? If so, please add the self-study tag!

Answer (score 1):

Taking a stab at your question, I've produced this function which takes some specifications of $\lambda$ and the level of the confidence interval for sample sizes and returns confidence bounds. This is just a starting point, though, to get you on the right track, since it appears that this is a homework assignment or problem for a class.

```
MC  <- function(n,lambda=1, alpha=0.95){
        x       <- rexp(n, lambda)
        lower   <- mean(x)+qt((1-alpha)/2, n-1)*sqrt(var(x))
        upper   <- mean(x)-qt((1-alpha)/2, n-1)*sqrt(var(x))
        return(cbind(lower, upper))
}
n   <- seq(from=2, to=22, by=1)
y   <- MC(n)

plot(n, y[,1], ylim=c(-10, 10), col="blue", xlab="sample size", ylab="95% confidence interval")
points(n, y[,2], col="red")
```